# woocommerce update date in myAccount after status change

Tags: woocommerce

Hello i have a Question.

If i change the status of an order from the Admin, the customer needs to get a last status changed date on the myaccount page in my orders.

Do you have any Idea how to implement this?

Comment: What have you tried already?

Answer (score 0):

```html
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
 exit;
}

?>
<p><?php
 /* translators: 1: order number 2: order changed date 3: order status */
 printf(
  __( 'Ihre Bestellung #%1$s vom %4$s ist %3$s.<br> Letzte Statusänderung am %2$s.<br><br>', 'woocommerce' ),
  '<mark class="order-number">' . $order->get_order_number() . '</mark>',
  '<mark class="order-date">' . wc_format_datetime( $order->get_date_modified() ) . '</mark>',
  '<mark class="order-status">' . wc_get_order_status_name( $order->get_status() ) . '</mark>',
  '<mark class="order-date">' . wc_format_datetime( $order->get_date_created() ) . '</mark>'
 );
?></p>

<?php if ( $notes = $order->get_customer_order_notes() ) : ?>
 <h2><?php _e( '<br>Order updates', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>
 <ol class="woocommerce-OrderUpdates commentlist notes">
  <?php foreach ( $notes as $note ) : ?>
  <li class="woocommerce-OrderUpdate comment note">
   <div class="woocommerce-OrderUpdate-inner comment_container">
    <div class="woocommerce-OrderUpdate-text comment-text">
     <p class="woocommerce-OrderUpdate-meta meta"><?php echo date_i18n( __( 'l jS \o\f F Y, h:ia', 'woocommerce' ), strtotime( $note->comment_date ) ); ?></p>
     <div class="woocommerce-OrderUpdate-description description">
      <?php echo wpautop( wptexturize( $note->comment_content ) ); ?>
     </div>
       <div class="clear"></div>
      </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
   </div>
  </li>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
 </ol>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_view_order', $order_id ); ?>
```

I added a new mark class with get_date_modified.

Then it shows me the last Date i modified the status.
I only want to see the Text "Letzte Statusänderung am %2$s" with the Date, if selected status is "wc-completed".

So i need code, that only shows text and date of modified status if the status of the order is wc-completed.

I dont know how to realize it another way.
I attached a Screenshot to visualize what i want to create.[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5LkZ.png)